# Removing empty values after importing CSV file

Tags: import, data, csv-format

I am trying to import a CSV file with the following structure:

- the 1st column has 15 values,
- the 2nd column has 10 values,
- and 3rd column has 15 values.

But when I import and try to access the 2nd column, it shows 5 commas (, , , , ,)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a1 = Import["data.csv", {"Data", All, All}]
```

so I get the following output:

```
{{"", 1, 2}, {1, 24.479, 24.4857}, {2, 24.6406, 24.5881}, {3, 24.8059,
   24.8043}, {4, 24.9217, 24.9197}, {5, 25.0553, 24.9319}, {6, 
  25.1328, 25.0986}, {7, 25.2248, 25.2658}, {8, 25.3725, 25.3393}, {9,
   25.4888, 25.4905}, {10, 25.6224, 25.6009}, {11, "", 25.7327}, {12, 
  "", 25.8424}, {13, "", 25.9748}, {14, "", 26.1249}, {15, "", 26.1774}}
```

and when I access the 2nd column,

```
ao = a1[[All, 2]]
```

I get the following

```
{1, 24.479, 24.6406, 24.8059, 24.9217, 25.0553, 25.1328, 25.2248,   
25.3725, 25.4888, 25.6224, "", "", "", "", ""}
```

Is there any way to get rid of commas/spaces without doing it manually?

Comment: it will help if you put a link to your .csv file so one can try. What happens if you do `Import[
"data.csv","Data"]` ?

Comment: @Nasser thanks edited.

Comment: I meant a link to the .csv file itself.  So one can download it and try. It seems some fields are empty in your file.

Comment: When you import csv file with empty fields, Mathematica put empty string "" in that field when importing. That is why you see the `, , , ,  ,` in there.   That right solution is to fix your data so that there are no empty fields. If you remove these fields are importing, you will get ragged array.

Comment: Use `dta /. "" -> Nothing`, where `dta` is your data file.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks. It works.

Comment: CSV import has an "EmptyFields" option that lets you control how these are handled.  For example:  `Import["data.csv", "EmptyFields"->Missing[]]` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html

Answer (score 0):

will

```
ao/.""->Sequence[]
```

work?

Or may be better to do `a1 /. "" -> 0`, as it will keep the structure of your table.

Comment: Please include an example of how your solutions work on the list in the question.

Comment: I do not think replacing empty field with zero is good idea. Because when looking at the data inside Mathematica, how will now one know if the zero was from the original file (i.e. original data) or it was introduced manually  later on?